# Redirect users on specific text

Tags: anchor

I have a project and I have a little error like:

I have a form and above and mysql query and if I had errors I will redirect users on an specific text like that:

```
redirect("comunitate.php?c=".$_GET['c']."&forum=".$_GET['forum']."&topic=".$_GET['topic']."&pagina=".$_GET['pagina']."#greseala");
```

*redirect is my own function who do an redirect on specific page

For example: The script should to redirect on `comunitate.php?c=1&forum=1&topic=1&pagina=1#greseala` , and on the page i have

```
<a name="greseala">bla bla bla</a>
```

The big problem is that I see the error mesage(greseala) when I run the form and when I redirect the user on the error part text it disappears.

Why? Where is my fault?

Comment: someone? one answear?